# PHP - FORM TO MAIL NOT WORKING

Tags: php

Okay, so I've followed a tutorial and just changed some of the variables and created them. I have a HTML and PHP code below, what's wrong with the PHP that's causing it not too work? Any ideas.

```html
<?php
 
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
 
     
 
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
 
    $email_to = " MY EMAIL ";
 
    $email_subject = "FORM SUBMISSION";
 
     
 
    // validation expected data exists
 
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['address']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
 
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
 
    }
 
     
 
    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
 
    $address = $_POST['address']; // required
 
    $email = $_POST['email']; // required
 
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
 
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required
 
     
 
    $error_message = "";
 
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
 
     
 
    function clean_string($string) {
 
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
 
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
 
    }
 
     
 
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($address)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";
 
     
 
     
 
// create email headers
 
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
 
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message);  
 
?>
 
 
 
<?php
  header('Location: MY LINK IS HERE BUT NOT WORKING');
?>

<?php
 
}
 
?>
```

Form

```
<div class="row contact-form">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Get In Touch</h3>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <form name="email" action="php/mail.php" method="POST">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="input-label">Name <span class="star-red">*</span>
            </p>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-input-wide" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="input-label">Address</p>
            <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-input-wide">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <form name="send-mail" action="php/mail.php" method="POST">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="input-label">Telephone <span class="star-red">*</span>
            </p>
            <input type="tel" name="telephone" id="telephone" class="form-input-wide" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="input-label">Email <span class="star-red">*</span>
            </p>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-input-wide" required>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p class="input-label">Message <span class="star-red">*</span>
          </p>
          <textarea name="message" id="message" style="width:100% !important;" rows="6" required></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="submit" class="submit-button">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          &nbsp
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

If there is anything that I need to change? I think the error messages may be breaking the PHP.

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: Change `died($error_message);` to `die($error_message);` and it will tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: I have updated my code now and my redirect after the form submit is breaking the php now.  
<?php
  header('Location: LINK TO OTHER PAGE);
?>
<?php
}
?> 

OTHER THAN THIS ERROR THE FORM NOW SENDS TO EMAIL. JUST NEED TO WORK ON REDIRECT!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two things wrong in the PHP script:

```
!isset($_POST['address`']) ||
needs to be
!isset($_POST['address']) ||
```

and

```
if(strlen($messages) < 2) {
needs to be
if(strlen($message) < 2) {
```

Maybe you can look into the usage of some "form validators" for some better usability. It would be a bit nicer to show the same form again but then with error messages attached to them, in stead of stopping the script with an error message.

EDIT:

For the header redirect: remove the whitespaces. The header('...') function needs to run before any browser output. Now there are whitespaces outputted to the browser. So remove "? >" and "< ? php"

```
?>



<?php
  header('Location: MY LINK IS HERE BUT NOT WORKING');
```